# How to assign image as variable taken from web scraping?

Tags: python, image, web, web-scraping

Using the link of a product from Amazon and its id, how we can assign an image as a variable in python? As we do get_text() and assign to a variable with text.

To get the title of the product we simply use:-

```
title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
```

But for the image what we can do?

Answer (score 1):

For image you can get its url - `src` in `<img scr="image.jpg">`

```
img_url = soup.find("img").get('src')
```

Later you can use this url with `requests` or `urllib` to download image to local file.

You can also download to memory and edit with module `PIL` before you save it in file.